# Eclipse ABAP Development: Cannot Retrieve Connection configuration

Tags: linux, eclipse, configuration, abap, sap-gui

I have installed ABAP Development Tools on Eclipse 4.2 and Kubuntu 12.04 64 bit and everything went fine.

When I try to create a new ABAP Project and search for configured SAP Connections on the SAP GUI (I have SAP GUI for Java 7.30 rev 3) Eclipse shows the following error:

"Configuration not found in settings file '/home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/settings', with include 'null', and message server 'null'"

I verified that file '/home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/settings' is present and not empty; here is the content:

```
############################################################
#
# file    : /home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/settings
# created : 08.05.2012 12:42:08 CEST
# encoding: UTF-8
#
############################################################
@logonFrameY = "83"
@logonFrameX = "137"
@GLF_showDetailCol = "1"
@GLF_ColumnState = "0 / 75"
@logonFrame_2_X = "970"
@logonFrame_2_Y = "241"
@frameWidth = "778"
@frameHeight = "900"
@logonFrame_2_Width = "348"
@logonFrame_2_Height = "451"
@lookAndFeelDefault = "Tradeshow"
@propFont = "Roboto Cn"
@fixedFont = "Ubuntu Mono"
@labelFont = "Roboto"
@genFont = "Roboto Cn"
@forceLongWindowTitle = "true"
@showListboxKeyAlways = "true"
@listboxSortByKey = "true"
@overwrite = "false"
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about this problem?

I tried on a Windows Virtual Machine and everything went fine.

Comment: There are no connection settings in the configuration file you quote. Are you able to access the SAP system from the GUI itself?

Comment: +1 for making me aware there is something like ABAP Development Tools for Eclipse.

Comment: Yes i'm able to connect to the GUI. In Unix-like systems there is another configuration file called connections (/home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/connections in my case)

Comment: why the hell would you want to do this, ever tried SE80? :D but also +1, never knew before that something like this exists.

Comment: @zyrex yes I tried and I use it now and that's because I think an IDE would speed up my work a lot (Advanced code completion, Refactoring, Renaming, Call Hierarchy). Have you ever developed with a modern IDE? :D

Comment: I also develop mobile apps with ABAP workbench :D the only lack I found is in syntax/code-compl. for javascript / html .. everything else is perfect :) did you get it running? would love to test it.

Comment: Well no, I didn't and I stopped trying, from what I understand some changes are required in client systems and I can't bother their stuff for my personal tests! :D

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a really old question but just in case you still have this issue (I have it on my mac all the time) add the following two entries to the bottom of that settings file:

```
@INCLUDE = "file:///home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/connections"
@MESSAGESERVER = "file:///home/dfabbri/.SAPGUI/message_servers"
```

Then create the two files above in that path (connections should already be there), message_servers can be empty. Hope this helps.